# Fourier transform invariant functions other than the bell curve?

Tags: fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, fourier-series

Are there any functions that are their own Fourier transforms other than $e^{-\pi x^2} $?

Comment: have you tried "Google"? any other efforts?

Comment: I gave an [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21189/6633) to this question on stats.SE

Answer (score 3):

There is a complete characterization of the probability densities that are (modulo a constant factor) their own Fourier transforms (aka characteristic functions) in a paper of K. Schladitz and H.J. Engelbert: 
"On probability density functions which are their own characteristic functions", 
Theory Probab. Appl., vol. 40 (1995) pp. 577–581. The class is surprisingly large.